# Using Extt Js 4.2 and Exjs 3.4 together

Tags: extjs

Currently I am using Extjs 3 and Ext js 4 version together in one application. Now in a JS file which is created in Ext Js 3 i have to create and object of widget which is created in extjs 4. Can u please suggest some ways to do this?

Comment: That sounds kinda tricky :p. I have no idea how to do it but if you get it work please let me know :D

Comment: Can you please tell me why are you using two versions 3.4 and 4.2 in  same application?